# Allow access to web app made in reactjs, redux, only if from valid referer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I am looking for an alternative of .htaccess file method to allow visitors only through valid referrer, for a react JS, redux app. I am very new to nodejs and I just setup an app following instructions.

I want to achieve the results of this .htaccess file

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from subdomain.domain.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.subdomain.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}   !^$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)         http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R,NE]
```

Do .htaccess works for nodejs too?

Comment: React and Redux are client-side technologies (i.e. run in the browser) and have nothing to do with server matters (like Referrer header). What are you using as your server?

Comment: I am using node.

Comment: Nodejs is just a runtime. Are you using [ExpressJs](https://expressjs.com/)?